# Split ul to more ul's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, while-loop, each

I have made a script with jQuery. The script split a list of li's, to more ul's. When the list is moer than 10 li items the list must be split in more ul's.
I have made the script in this post.

But the script is not working. What I did wrong here.
The script is for a submenu in the navigation. When the navigation li items are more than 4 than the ul of li items must be splitted in two ul's. How can I fix this script. Thanks!

```
submenu();
function submenu() {
    $(".submenu").each(function () {
        if($("li", this).length > 4){
            $(this).closest(".submenu").addClass("width-2")

            var submenu = $(this).closest(".submenu");
            var $bigList = $(this), group;

            while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(8)').remove()).length) {
                $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo(submenu);
            }

        }
        if($("li", this).length > 10){
            $(this).closest(".submenu").addClass("width-3")

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: Would really help if you could set this up in http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: I have make this JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xtFPy/1/
When you hover over the items. You see the submenu. When the li items are more than 4. Than the width of the submenu is set to 320 pixels.

But the problem is. When the li items is more than 4. The li items must be splitted in two ul's. And not 1.

Comment: What is `group`, and seems like that `while` loop will never end ?

Comment: When i run the script. The while loop is going broken en my browser is stop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but this code will split each submenu UL into more submenus of the specified size while keeping all items in the original DOM order:

```
function splitSubmenu(maxNumItems) {
    $(".submenu").each(function () {

        // get all child li tags
        var list$ = $(this).children("li");
        var num, nextAfter$, after$ = $(this);

        // as long as the current list it too long, loop
        while (list$.length > maxNumItems) {
            // decide how many to remove this iteration
            num = Math.min(maxNumItems, list$.length - maxNumItems);
            // create new UL tag, append num items to it 
            // and insert it into the DOM
            nextAfter$ = $('<ul class="submenu">')
                .append(list$.slice(maxNumItems, maxNumItems + num))
                .insertAfter(after$);
            // update insertion point for next loop iteration
            after$ = nextAfter$;
            // remove the items we just took out from the current jQuery object
            list$ = list$.filter(function(index) {
                return(index < maxNumItems || index >= 2 * maxNumItems);
            });
        }
    });
}

splitSubmenu(4);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VMjvQ/.

I did not understand what you were trying to do with the additional classes so that part is not included.